# product of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices, then whether $vec\{A\}vec^{T}\{B\}$ is Hermtian positive semidefinite? (vec{A} means column vectorization of the matrix $A$)

Comment: $\text{vec}(A)(\text{vec}(B))^T$ will have a zero-eigenspace of dimension $n-1$, since it is a rank $1$ matrix. So everything turns on whether the remaining eigenvalue is positive or negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. There is no reason why $\operatorname{vec}(A)\operatorname{vec}(B)^T$ is Hermitian in the first place. For a counterexample, consider $(1,0,0,0)^T(0,0,0,1)$.